# Unknown column 'shipping_city' in 'where clause' afterSearch Grid Table

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to use the `afterSearch` in a Admin Grid but when I try to filter a result I'm getting an `Unknown column 'shipping_city' in 'where clause'` where shipping_city is the custom column I added.

I found a sample [here](https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-add-a-custom-column-in-order-grid-in-magento-2/?unapproved=885&moderation-hash=bc29bcc57b29cf44a86bd104cf3b1374#comment-885) but just as the title state I'm getting an error. Below is my class that do this query and throws the error

```
class Grid
{
    public static $table = 'customer_entity';
    public static $leftJoinTable = 'customer_address_entity';

    public function afterSearch($intercepter, $collection)
    {
        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {
            $leftJoinTableName = $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$leftJoinTable);

            $collection
                ->getSelect()
                ->joinLeft(
                    ['co'=>$leftJoinTableName],
                    "co.entity_id = main_table.default_shipping",
                    ['shipping_city' => 'co.city']
                );

            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where);
            // echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();die;
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

When trying to print the generated query I got this

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `co`.`city` AS `shipping_city` FROM `customer_entity` AS `main_table`
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity` AS `co` ON co.entity_id = main_table.default_shipping 
WHERE (`shipping_city` LIKE '%Maidenhead%')
```

As you can see the `shipping_city` is the custom column so whenever I tried to search in this column it's passing this parameter. But I can't get a result and it's throwing an error. How can I fix this please.. badly need your help. Thanks